# Port forwarded public IP not reachable from private network but from outside

Tags: networking, router, nat, unifi

I am using double NAT, I can not put my provider provided modem in bridge mode so I put my unifi USG in it´s DMZ.

On my USG I set up forwarded ports, before I migrated my subnet away from a 10.0.0.0/8 subnet (I had to create a Work vlan as I had IP conflicts with the work vpn) to a 192.168.0.0/22 subnet I could access my public IP from inside my network and outside.

After switching subents I can only access it from outside. I heard of NAT reflection but I can not find the settings in the USG and I had not changed anything in that regard. My unifi usg seems to drop it.

```
Tracing route to home.my.domain [<myPublicIP>]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  gateway [192.168.0.1]
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

Is it because now the modem and unifi are part of 192.168.0.0/16?

- Old unifi subnet: 10.0.0.0/8 I know it was way too large
- New unifi subnet: 192.168.0.0/22
- Old modem subnet: 192.168.1.0/24
- New modem subnet: 192.168.255.0/24

Comment: Since your Unifi thing doesn't have the public IP address, it's not what would be doing hairpin NAT. It's your provider's modem (which really is a router, too.) // Your inner router surely supports capturing packets, so you can investigate actual network traffic.

Comment: @DanielB strangely this only occurred after I switched subnets